# Bootstrap 4 sticky bottom nav bar - main content scrolling under the bottom nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've tried and tried to make this work but noting seems to do what i'm expecting.

I want the make sure the "main" content (i.e the images in this example), not disappear underneath the bottom nav bar.

If you see in the jsfiddle below the image gets half cut off. And this is not the desired effect.

Is it possible to treat the "Main" content as a separate scroll-able entity?

My goal is to have the last image FULLY shown on the page when you scroll to the bottom.

Current code here.

https://jsfiddle.net/6bcyeswz/4/

and here

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href=" /static/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/static/funcs.js?v=3"></script>
    <script src="/static/confetti.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #F3F9E3">
<div class="container-fluid mb-1" style="background-color: #628B48">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark secondary-color">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>TESTINGWEBSITE</strong></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-6"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent-6" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-6">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick='navigate(getCookie("name"))'>Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Top Rated</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                       title="Login/Sign up to access">My Stats</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-6" data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="false">Dropdown </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-secondary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-6">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="inline-block text-Light">
                <a href="#" class="text-Light">Login
                    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-door-open" fill="currentColor"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M1 15.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-13a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM11.5 2H11V1h.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13 2.5V15h-1V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5z"/>
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M10.828.122A.5.5 0 0 1 11 .5V15h-1V1.077l-6 .857V15H3V1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .43-.495l7-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .398.117z"/>
                        <path d="M8 9c0 .552.224 1 .5 1s.5-.448.5-1-.224-1-.5-1-.5.448-.5 1z"/>
                    </svg></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container pt-2">
   


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTyhk-6WDKDsgDtpVY8bZxkVu6dfVkkmuAWYg&usqp=CAU">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTyhk-6WDKDsgDtpVY8bZxkVu6dfVkkmuAWYg&usqp=CAU">
                              <img class="img-thumbnail" src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTyhk-6WDKDsgDtpVY8bZxkVu6dfVkkmuAWYg&usqp=CAU">
                                        <img class="img-thumbnail" src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTyhk-6WDKDsgDtpVY8bZxkVu6dfVkkmuAWYg&usqp=CAU">
        </div>
    </div>

        <!---- nav bar bottom fixed for rating photos ---->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-bottom">
        <form method="post" id="form">
            <div class="form-group pt-2">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <input type="hidden" id="image" name="image" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" id="person" name="person" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" id="answer" name="answer" value="">
                    <div class="col">
                        <button type="button" name="love" class="btn btn-success form-control" onclick='post("love")'>
                            <div class="p2">
                                I Love It
                                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-check"
                                     fill="currentColor"
                                     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                          d="M10.97 4.97a.75.75 0 0 1 1.071 1.05l-3.992 4.99a.75.75 0 0 1-1.08.02L4.324 8.384a.75.75 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.094 2.093 3.473-4.425a.236.236 0 0 1 .02-.022z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <button type="button" name="yes" class="btn btn-success form-control" onclick='post("yes")'>
                            <div class="p2">Yes</div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <button type="button" name="no" class="btn btn-danger form-control" onclick='post("no")'>
                            <div class="p2">No</div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <button type="button" name="hate" class="btn btn-danger form-control" onclick='post("hate")'>
                            <div class="p2">
                                Hate It
                                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-exclamation-circle-fill"
                                     fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                          d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8 4a.905.905 0 0 0-.9.995l.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 0 1.1 0l.35-3.507A.905.905 0 0 0 8 4zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </nav>

</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class that simulate sticky-bottom behavior:

```
.sticky-bottom {
  position: sticky !important;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Then replace replace `fixed-bottom` in your navbar with `sticky-bottom`:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-bottom">
```

Comment: Cheers, exactly what I needed.